# How to use generic inside the function when typing with a type alias?

Tags: typescript

Let say I have a function like this(I know it is a nonsense):

```js
const fn = <T>(a: number) => {
  return a as unknown as Promise<T>
}
```

When I separate the type and the function with type alias like this:

```js
type Fn = <T>(a: number) => Promise<T>
const fn: Fn = <T>(a) => {
  return a as unknown as Promise<T>
}
```

I will get the following error:

```
Parameter 'a' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Why is that? How can I use generic when I type with type alias?

Comment: What's the difference between `type Fn = <T>(a: number) => Promise<T>` and `type Fn = (a: number) => Promise<any>`? You introduce a generic constraint, but you're not constraining anything.

Comment: I know it is non sense but I want to keep it simple to reproduce my question there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're working with generic lambdas, TypeScript (as far as I'm concerned) won't allow you implicit 'any' types in the argument list. A solution (workaround) would be to just add the type:

```
type Fn = <T>(a: number) => Promise<T>
const fn: Fn = <T>(a: number) => {
  return a as unknown as Promise<T>
}
```

So far I'm not aware of any other solution that would enable you to use lambdas with inferred argument types.

Comment: Will that compile?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I have tested it, indeed, it will compile

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen if I've helped you solve your problem, consider marking this answer as a solution

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen sorry, didn't see you weren't OP

Comment: That's frustrating. Basically I have to write the type twice if I use lambda

Comment: @JohnWinston unfortunately, you do. I can't think of any workaround right now